# How implement seen by and message carbon feature in XMPP ( Openfire server) using Strophe.js?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe, instant-messaging

I am trying to develop a **chat application** based on **XMPP** using **Strophe.js**.

**Important Points:-**

*1) Server- Openfire 3.9.3*

*2) client- Strophe.js*

Messaging is working fine but I want to implement the ***seen by*** and ***message carbon
feature***  just like *Whatsapp* and *Facebook messenger*. and I know it can be  done with the help of **XEP-0333** and **XEP-0280** protocol I just want to know that is there any **plugin** available for **Strophe.js**  to handle the **XEP-0333** and **XEP-0280** packages just to save time ?

Comment: There seems to be a strophe.js plugin for XEP-0280: Message Carbons. https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugin-message-carbons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no plugins available for Strophe to implement XEP-0333 and XEP-0280